# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> erorr in js when using api

Tags: javascript, api

First Time I am Working with APIs and this error came
this is index.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNbbu.jpg)

and this is script.js

```
window.onload = function(){
const API_URL = "https://api.github.com/users/";

const main = document.getElementById('main');

const form = document.getElementById('form')

const search = document.getElementById('search')

async function getUsers(user) {
    const resp = await fetch(API_URL + user);
    const respData = await resp.json();

    createUserCard(respData);
}

function createUserCard(user) {
    const cardHTML = `
    <div class="card">
    <div>
    <img src="${user.avatar_url}" alt="${user.name}" />
     </div>
    <div>
    <h2>${user.name}</h2>
    <p>${user.bio}</p>
    <ul>
    <li> ${user.followers}</li>
    <li>${user.following} </li>
    <li> ${user.public_repos}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    `;

    main.innerHTML = cardHTML;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = search.value;

    if (user) {
        getUsers(user);

        search.value = '';
    }
});
}
```

if there is any mistake please help any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like, in your HTML, the ID of your `<input>` is "search ", not "search". That's probably the issue, since the element is null!

Comment: Thanks, Now The error is solved you are correct.